# Cannot convert argument "1", with value: "", for "InsertBefore"

Tags: powershell-2.0

I was trying to add a child node() to a reportserver.config file, but i got an error which i actually dont know how after all efforts. Below is what i did.

$webConfigPath = "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS10_50.SNDPRO\Reporting Services\ReportServer\rsreportserver.config"

$xml =[xml] (get-content $webConfigPath)

$child = $xml.CreateElement("RSWindowsNegotiate")

$xml.Configuration.Authentication.AuthenticationTypes.InsertBefore($child, "$xml.Configuration.Authentication.AuthenticationTypes.RSWindowsNTLM")

$xml.Save($webConfigPath)

And the error is: Cannot convert argument "1", with value: "", for "InsertBefore" to type "System.Xml.XmlNode": "Cannot convert the "" value of type "System.String" to type "System.Xml.XmlNode"."

Many thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 1):

I think powershell does something weird when using an empty XML element as a property (in this case RSWindowsNTLM). Try this:

```
$RSWindowsNTLM = $xml.Configuration.Authentication.AuthenticationTypes.SelectSingleNode("RSWindowsNTLM");
$xml.Configuration.Authentication.AuthenticationTypes.InsertBefore($child, $RSWindowsNTLM)
```